# Forcing Text direction for LeadingMarginSpan2

Tags: java, android

I'm using `LeadingSpanMargin2` as suggested to style my `TextView` so that it would flow around an `Image`, the problem is the text I set is dynamic and can be rtl or ltr.

I tried anything I could think of to fix the `leadingMargin` so that it would be either right or left in both cases, to no avail.

Also the I've tried `FlowTextView` widget posted in github and it doesn't work well in rtl cases, so please do not suggest that.

Many thanks.

Here's the code I use, which was suggested in another answer:

```
public void setFlowText(CharSequence text, int width , int height, TextView messageView)
{
    float textLineHeight = messageView.getPaint().getTextSize();

    // Set the span according to the number of lines and width of the image
    int lines = (int)Math.ceil(height / textLineHeight);
    //For an html text you can use this line: SpannableStringBuilder ss = (SpannableStringBuilder)Html.fromHtml(text);
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);
    ss.setSpan(new MyLeadingMarginSpan2(lines, width), 0, ss.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    //ss.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE), 0, ss.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    messageView.setText(ss);

    // Align the text with the image by removing the rule that the text is to the right of the image
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)messageView.getLayoutParams();
    int[]rules = params.getRules();
    rules[RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF] = 0;
}

public class MyLeadingMarginSpan2 implements LeadingMarginSpan2 {
    private int margin;
    private int lines;
    private boolean wasDrawCalled = false;
    private int drawLineCount = 0;

    public MyLeadingMarginSpan2(int lines, int margin) {
        this.margin = margin;
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLeadingMargin(boolean first) {
        boolean isFirstMargin = first;
        // a different algorithm for api 21+
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            this.drawLineCount = this.wasDrawCalled ? this.drawLineCount + 1 : 0;
            this.wasDrawCalled = false;
            isFirstMargin = this.drawLineCount <= this.lines;
        }

        return isFirstMargin ? this.margin : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void drawLeadingMargin(Canvas c, Paint p, int x, int dir, int top, int baseline, int bottom, CharSequence text, int start, int end, boolean first, Layout layout) {
        this.wasDrawCalled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLeadingMarginLineCount() {
        return this.lines;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the some unknown reason you can get left margin by passing:

```
ss.setSpan(new MyLeadingMarginSpan2(lines, width), 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

and to get right margin you need to pass:

```
ss.setSpan(new MyLeadingMarginSpan2(lines, width), 1, 2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

I don't know what is going on there, but this works!

Comment: Pay attention to the length of your text. i.e : ss.setSpan(..., 1, 2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); Your text length should be > 2 !